# Why Even after adding checks in if block typescript throws error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have a controller `function` that handles update cart HTTP request in the `express` server like -

```
export async function updateCart(
  req: TypedRequestBody<{
    addItem?: {
      productId: string
      variantId: string
      quantity: number
    }
    updateItem?: {
      productId: string
      variantId: string
      quantity: number
    }
    removeItems?: Array<string>
  }>,
  res: Response,
) {
  const {farmerId} = req.params
  let cart = await CartModel.findOne({farmerId})
  if (!cart) cart = await CartModel.create({farmerId})

  if (req.body.addItem) {
    const itemIndex = cart.items.findIndex(item => item.productId.toString() === req.body.addItem.productId)
    if (itemIndex !== -1) throw new createError.UnprocessableEntity('Item already exists in cart')
    cart.items.push(req.body.addItem)
  }

  if (req.body.updateItem) {
    const itemIndex = cart.items.findIndex(item => item.productId.toString() === req.body.updateItem.productId)
    if (itemIndex === -1) throw new createError.UnprocessableEntity('Item does not exists in cart')
    cart.items[itemIndex] = req.body.updateItem
  }

  if (req.body.removeItems) {
    cart.items = cart.items.filter(item => !req.body.removeItems.includes(item.productId.toString()))
  }

  cart = await cart.save()

  return res.send(new HttpResponse(true, {cart}))
}
```

As you can see that I've added checks before adding or updating cart items.
But typescript compiler throws the following errors -

[Error Screenshot][1]

> src/controllers/farmer.ts:288:82 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
> 288     const itemIndex = cart.items.findIndex(item => item.productId.toString() === req.body.addItem.productId)

> src/controllers/farmer.ts:294:82 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
> 294     const itemIndex = cart.items.findIndex(item => item.productId.toString() === req.body.updateItem.productId)

> src/controllers/farmer.ts:300:45 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
> 300     cart.items = cart.items.filter(item => !req.body.removeItems.includes(item.productId.toString()))

**UPDATE -**

`TypedRequestBody` interface -

```
import {Query} from 'express-serve-static-core'
import {Request} from 'express'

interface MyRequest extends Request {
  auth?: TokenData
}

export interface TypedRequestBody<T> extends MyRequest {
  body: T
}
```

Why the error is coming even after I've added checks in `if`?

Comment: I would expect this error to occur. What is the question?

Comment: Why the error is coming even after I've added checks in if?

Comment: Works like expected, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42848